# JavaScript: Any way to create a X Axis grid, and use it in game where characters are placed?

Tags: javascript, node.js

kind of hard to explain what I want to get done but I will try.
Basically using Node.js, Jade and Express:
Is it possible to make like a map, or just a line/grid along X axis and save positions of elements (placed by users) on it?

Example:
I have a website, I want users to login and then be presented with this grid where users drag'n'drop their photos. So say: User#1 places his photo to the left of the grid, User#2 logins and sees grid with photo of user#1 on left side of grid, he can drag'n'drop his photo near him too or somewhere away from User#1.

How do I do this? So it saves position along X axis basically.

Full story:

I am building chat application where users can upload their own avatars (picture basically).
So far I have done: sockets open, chat works two directions perfectly, data is transferred and user online list is updated as user enters/leaves.

I want it to:
1) User connects.
2) Chat window loads,
3) All user avatars are loaded on X axis on screen (basically a line of avatars/photos/pics).
4) User can click and drag his avatar/photo/pic along this X axis and I want it to stay there.

So basically a positioning system that saves coordinates along X axis and when user rejoins it spawns his avatar where he drag-dropped it.

Comment: This is really too broad to discuss here, as they are likely a number of sub-components needed to achieve the overall functionality - generation of grid display, web page polling to get content updates, user interaction, etc.

Comment: So this is basically a "chat" app where the text messages are replaced by (x-coordinate, object-id) pairs and appropriately encoded/decoded by the front end?

Comment: Your question is way too broad to properly answer. Be more specific. Right now "Yes Javascript can make arrays" is a complete answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your requirements (probably way more of them) can be done via javascript. on both sides. on server/node side. you only need socket.io (with or without expressjs) for your chat server & position updater. you can use different broadcasts with socket.io to update positions of avatars between them along with chat messages. (consider that you have 100 clients connected. a basic ajax query function will make a huge load on backend) on client side just use any jquery plugin to draw user interface & it's interactions. jquery ui draggable is perfect i guess. 
here is the links you need to use.

http://jqueryui.com/draggable/

http://socket.io/

Comment: Guess that's the best answer I will get, thanks for pointing me the right direction.